# Short hand for method and field access modifiers in a Java class?

Tags: java, class, access-modifiers

Is there a short hand for defining the access modifiers of a classes fields and methods? More in a C++ style, I've searched but keep coming up with sites explaining what the purpose of each modifier is rather than a short hand.

```
public class myNum {
    public int getNum() { return 0; }
    public void setNum(int n) { int num = n; }
    private int num;
    private String value;
}
```

Could become

```
public class myNum {
    public:
        int getNum() { return 0; }
        void setNum(int n) { int num = n; }
    private:
        int num;
        String value;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For methods nope. 
For variables you could try

`public int n1,n2,n3..n;`

`private int n1,n2,n3..n;`

But as you can see it can become messy quickly. 
And even then, it doesn't allow for different types under one access modifier.

But really nope.

Comment: Blah, that's what I was worried about. Grouping them that way as you said gets messy and isn't the best for coding style and readability. Thanks for confirming what I thought. Have to wait for 7 mins before I can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no short for defining methods, Eclipse can automatically generate getter and setter methods for you.